# View memcache items in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

Trying to view items in memcache in GAE.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7245
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/08/app-engine-171-released.html

These links say "Namespaces in the Memcache Viewer - The Admin Console now supports retrieving memcache values that are stored in a non-default namespace."

But I still couldn't the view item trying different combinations.

tried, ns.key, ns_key, key (where ns is namespace, key is key set in the program).
I use Development SDK 1.7.6, with GO runtime. What should I enter it in the search space as seen in the picture, or what is the best way?

[image]

Comment: Both of those links are referring to the *live* admin panel, which has a "namespace" text field. I don't know of any way to do this in the development server's admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently implemented in the development server (but is available in the production admin console as pointer by [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3737/jesse-rusak) in the comment).

You should open [a new feature request](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/issues/entry) in [dev_appserver2](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/) projects.

If you feel like contributing it yourself, you could easily add support by patching:

- [`memcache_viewer.html`](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/source/browse/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/templates/memcache_viewer.html#35) to add a new `<input>` field to capture the namespace.
- [`memcache_viewer.py`](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/source/browse/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/memcache_viewer.py#73) to add `namespace` arg to `memcache.get` call